# LazyTableImages vs SDWebImages

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In apple's lazyTableImages project when you first run images appear asynchronusly altough you haven't started scrolling. But in SDWebImage it is not like that. If you don't start to scroll, images don't start to appear. I couldn't succeed to populate LazyTableImages in my project. But i did SDWebImage. So i want to add that functionality as well. Is that possible? I want to download images when new cell is created. I know lazyTableImages does that job but i am not sure that SDWebImages does too. Because when i scroll the table images are already there like they are loaded before. 
Thank you for your answers..

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes. How would you achieve this? It sounds like you should probably look in more detail at both the `LazyTableImages` sample code and the `SDWebImage` source. It sounds as if you're maybe just trying to copy/paste a lot of code, and you'll really benefit from understanding how it actually all pulls together and works.

`SDWebImage` is just a `UIImageView` category, so is comparativly 'dumb' compares to Apple's sample code, which hooks into the table view's underlying scroll view to detect when you've finished scrolling and load in the cells that are displayed (to make it appear more responsive).

Once you're comfortable with *how* both those classes are achieving their asynchronous download you'll be in a much better position to start playing around with how they work.